# Problem running openni_launch on ros fuerte with Xtion pro live

Tags: openni, ros-fuerte, xtion, asus, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ros user!

I try to use a Asus Xtion pro live with ROs Fuerte and openni_launch.
I have made a lot of test but I have not been able to make it work.
It is always the same thing I have got this Error message :

```
[ERROR] [1337435292.200305197]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]

[ERROR] [1337435292.210206934]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
```

Exept this error every thing else seems alright. It detect the camera :

```
[ INFO] [1337435291.552393164]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1337435291.552631121]: 1. device on bus 001:03 is a PrimeSense Device (600) from PrimeSense (1d27) with serial id ''
[ INFO] [1337435291.554548510]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1337435291.687868149]: Opened 'PrimeSense Device' on bus 1:3 with serial number ''
```

But there is no message publish on the topic /camera/depth/points. I have tried different topics but none of then publish any message. I use RVIZ to see the topics.

I was previously running ros on Ubuntu 10.04 running on  VMWare Player. When I encourtered this error I decided to try on different Ubuntu version but
I have got the same error on each of the version I have tried.

I have tried Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04.
On ubuntu 12.04 I have got much more error so I concentred myself on ubuntu 11.10 which I suppose is the better version of Ubuntu to work with Asus Xtion.
I have even try to install ros fuerte from source but it doesn't resolve anything. Still the same error!

Now I don't know what to do.
Have I missed something?

I guess that with ros fuerte and openni_launch I have nothing else to install? right?
Openni Driver and everything else is package with openni_launch? right?

Any help apreciate.

Things in advance.

Regards.

Christophe.

EDIT TO MY INITIAL POST:

Yes all my previous try where done on VMWare. I have now installed Ubuntu 12.04 directly on my PC and now everything works fine! I am able to see point cloud in RVIZ! Thanks for taking time to answer me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34378/problem-running-openni_launch-on-ros-fuerte-with-xtion-pro-live/) by [Christophe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2344/christophe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2012-05-20**:
Were all your ubuntu test instances on a VM?

**Comment by [Christophe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2344/christophe/) on 2012-05-22**:
Yes all my previous try where done on VMWare. I have now installed Ubuntu 12.04 directly on my PC and now everything works fine! I am able to see point cloud in RVIZ! Thanks for taking time to answer me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those messages are normal when running the openni launch file.

There are at least two possibilities here:

- You haven't chosen an appropriate frame in rviz
- Your driver isn't publishing any messages

You can troubleshoot the point cloud topic without rviz by doing

`rostopic hz /camera/depth/points`

If you don't see any output within 30 seconds or so, there's a problem with your driver. If you see output indicating that the driver is publishing around 30Hz, the problem is with your rviz settings.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0